# issue with ftp client in android

Tags: android, ftp

i tried to upload image file from my android application to my Server using FTP Protocol..

i found this class in the internet but is not working fine.

this my code :

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
public class FileUpload {

/**
 * Upload a file to a FTP server. A FTP URL is generated with the following
 * syntax: ftp://user:password@host:port/filePath;type=i.
 * 
 * @param ftpServer
 *            , FTP server address (optional port ':portNumber').
 * @param user
 *            , Optional user name to login.
 * @param password
 *            , Optional password for user.
 * @param fileName
 *            , Destination file name on FTP server (with optional preceding
 *            relative path, e.g. "myDir/myFile.txt").
 * @param source
 *            , Source file to upload.
 * @throws MalformedURLException
 *             , IOException on error.
 */
public FileUpload() {
}

public void upload(String ftpServer, String user, String password,
        String fileName, File source) throws MalformedURLException,
        IOException {
    if (ftpServer != null && fileName != null && source != null) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("ftp://");
        // check for authentication else assume its anonymous access.
        if (user != null && password != null) {
            sb.append(user);
            sb.append(':');
            sb.append(password);
            sb.append('@');
        }
        sb.append(ftpServer);
        sb.append('/');
        sb.append(fileName);
        /*
         * type ==&gt; a=ASCII mode, i=image (binary) mode, d= file
         * directory listing
         */
        sb.append(";type=i");

        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlc.getOutputStream()); ///here i get an exception
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

            int i;
            // read byte by byte until end of stream
            while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(i);
            }
        } finally {
            if (bis != null)
                try {
                    bis.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            if (bos != null)
                try {
                    bos.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Input not available.");
    }
}
```

how i can fix this issue ?
Note : i called this method from another thread(not from main thread)..

Comment: `but is not working fine.` - you need to be specific: is there any error? Is the app crashing? What is the content of logcat?

Comment: its crashing and throw an exception error when i trying to use 
" bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlc.getOutputStream());"

Comment: What is the exception? Post your logcat...